# I run a .py script in my cmd and the error "ModuleNotFoundError" appears

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pyautogui

I created a script in python that needs the "pyautogui" so that it works the way I want. but when I open in cmd I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named 'PyAutoGui". I've search how to fix it, but they do not fix it or it's too complicated. How do I run my .py in cmd using "pyautogui" without having to open pycharm every time to use it?
i use python 3.7.2 64 bits (updated)

Error: http://prntscr.com/metcvt

Already tried to install python in another directory and another version.

```
import pyautogui

print("#####--##### ADVERTENCIAS #####-#####")

print("\nMantenha sempre seu mouse acima do objeto!")

print("Não coloque numeros exagerados.")

print("Nem todos os clicks podem ser executados, mas nunca sera mais que o 
solicitado.")

print("Para sua segurança inicie o programa com a janela ao lado do objeto")

def setup():

    clicks=int(input("\nQuantos clicks você deseja? "))

    pyautogui.click(clicks=clicks,interval=0.01)

    setup()

setup()
```

I expected that I could give an input and run my code, but what I get is just a error.

Comment: Hi, have you installed PyAutoGUI?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see here, I'm thinking that PyAutoGUI is not in a directory where it can be accessed via CMD. I'm also assuming that the PyAutoGUI package is included in your PyCharm project?

First, see if the package is in your system path with:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
#output
```

If it's not in one of those directories, it cannot be accessed with CMD. You can either put it in one of the listed directories, or add it to the `sys.path`, use this command:

```
>>> sys.path.append(r"[package directory]\\PyAutoGUI")
```

Now if you try running your script in CMD, it will work.

If you haven't actually installed PyAutoGUI yet, just run:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187694/discussion-on-answer-by-jlynchdesigns-i-run-a-py-script-in-my-cmd-and-the-error).

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using Python 2.7.9 (or greater) or Python 3.4 (or greater), then PIP comes installed with Python by default. If you still aren't able to use pip do the following:

For windows:
Right click on the below given link and select Save As... and save it to Downloads (not a compulsion) now open that folder and right-click in free space while holding shift, then select 'open PowerShell here' or 'open Command-prompt here', run in`python get-pip.py`

[get-pip.py installer script](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) or if you're using python 3.2 use: [get-pip for python 3.2](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/3.2/get-pip.py)

after that pip will install in your system now run `pip install pyautogui` or `pip3 install pyautogui`

Comment: in "pip/pip3 install pyautogui" i receive the error of invalid syntax, i tried in the py command line and in the normal command line.

Comment: try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then run `pip install pyautogui` you'll need admin privileges to run first command

Comment: all the commands that I give with the pip are giving syntax error

Comment: You should try uninstalling python and then reinstalling again from python.org

Comment: I'll try some more things and I'll reinstall, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

in your cmd:
pip install pyautogui
or
pip3 install pyautogui

should work

Comment: both give the error: "NameError: name 'pip / pip3' is not defined"